# Where can i get access driver to connect to java?

Tags: java, database

I have build an java application which uses ms access database. I have also created an installation package using nsis. The software works fine in my computer. But it will not work in computers with no ms access installed. So i have to bundle an access odbc driver with my installation package. But which should i choose. Where to get it.. I am totally confused. I hope you would have a fine answer. Thanx in Advance

Comment: This is confusing... do you connect to a remote MS Access database? If not you need MS Access (+license) on each and every PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience the ODBC driver to conntect to MS Access is part of every Windows installation.

You can use the JDBC/ODBC bridge to connect to it using a JDBC URL that doesn't require an ODBC-Datasource definition.

Assuming your Access database file is located in c:\Data\mydb.mdb, you should be able to connect using the following JDBC url:

```
jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\Data\mydb.mdb
```

I have never installed MS Access on my Windows PC and I can connect to mdb files without problems using that url.

This even works on non-englisch installations. I have a German Windows installation, but the above URL using the "english" driver name works without problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting remotely, you can probably use a [jdbc driver](http://www.easysoft.com/applications/microsoft-access/jdbc-odbc.html) or there's a really old thread [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/304252/JDBC/java/JDBC-driver-MS-Access) that says the JavaSDK has a JDBC/ODBC bridge driver built in.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you need the Microsoft Data Access Components ([MDAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937729.aspx)). It includes the Jet database engine, which is the backend of the Access database.